# Extra space on the right of the webpage causes horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I recently wrote a website with ASP.NET MVC 5. The website looks good except that there's always extra white space on the right side of the home page causing a horizontal scroll bar in the browser.

Moreover, the extra space only exists on the home page.

Here is the [url](http://116.62.241.205)

Comment: You should post relevant code here. Especially `width` and `overflow` properties and ofc the basic structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This space appears because you have a too large block in your page like in the screenshot:
[image]

So it pushes on the right and create the white space.

**EDIT**: There is a second one here:

[image]

Comment: he has a few places as example below

Comment: I adjusted the place in the screenshot, but the extra space still exists.... can you tell me all the other places you found with the same problem? Thanks. @לבנימלכה

Comment: @NJUHOBBY I saw the other place he was talking about. I edited my answer like that you can see where the problem is. If all is correct after that don't forget to accept the anwser :)

Comment: @Firefly I just realized that! Thanks for your answer, really appreciate it!